# Undefined control sequence in komacv.cls

Tags: document-classes, cv, undefined

I'm quite new to this forum, please be nice to me. I'm using Texlive on Ubuntu.

I'm trying to write a CV by using LaTeX, so I downloaded the komacv class files from CTAN and followed the instructions in the README file: I copied the documentation komacv.pdf and the examples older into the doc directory in my local tex directory, i.e.

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc
```

and ran the latex command on the .ins file, thereby creating the .cls file. Then I was supposed to move said .cls file and the .sty files into my local tex directory,

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex
```

, and run the texhash command on it, but when I did that the first time, Texlive always complained about not being able to find the komacv.cls, so I moved those folders into the latex subdirectory in my local tex directory. I ran texhash on the whole tex directory though.

Luckily, texlive is able to find the .cls now, however, it's complaining about an undefined control sequence in it.
This is the error message it's given me every time:

```
*(./example.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(./komacv.cls
Document Class: komacv 2017/04/12 v1.1 komacv class
! Undefined control sequence.
l.26 \changes
             {v1.1}{2017/04/12}{New macro headline, and new correspondent el...
?*
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? It'd be very nice of you if you helped me.

Comment: Please update your texlive distribution or at least try to install this package using `tlmgr`.

Comment: @TeXnician unfortunately updating via tlmgr won't fix this until probably July.

Answer (score 2):

The file on ctan has been updated in the last few days and has an error: when extracted it leaves the following line in the extracted class file.

```
\changes{v1.1}{2017/04/12}{New macro headline, and new correspondent elements headlinestyle, headlinecolor, headlinefont}
```

You should delete this line.

I have reported it to the class author, who was aware of the issue and is sending an update to CTAN.

Comment: Just wanted to tell you this ;-). I got the new version with miktex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I sent an email to the address in the file....